# is the order in which the PRs will be merged is important?

Tags: git, branch

Suppose I have a `main` branch and then, after a few commits, I create a new branch `feature1` starting from `main` and then, after other few commits, I create another `feature2` branch starting from `feature1` and then again, after other few commits, I create another `feature3` branch starting from `feature2`.

So the tree is something like this:

```
               main
                |
 a -- b -- c -- d
                 \       feature1
                  \          |
                   e -- f -- g 
                              \                       feature2
                               \                         |
                                h -- j -- k -- l -- m -- n
                                                          \    feature3
                                                           \     |
                                                            o -- p
```

I also created a PR for `feature1`, `feature2`, and `feature3` branches. When I visit the page of the PR of branch `feature1`, I see the differences of `feature1` compared to `main`. When I visit the page of the PR of branch `feature2`, I see the differences of `feature2` compared to `main` and since that `feature2` starts from `feature1`, there are a lot of differences, not only the one about commits `h-n` but also `e-g` and so on.

It seems ok to me because branches are created on top of others. Unfortunately the PR of `feature2` is difficult to review because there are many changes and this is the same (indeed worse) for the PR of `feature3`.

I have two main questions now:

1. In that case, is the order in which the PRs will be merged is important?
   Suppose a user merges PR `feature1`, then if I visit the page of PR `feature2`, what I see? Only the differences of commit e-g or I need to pull `main`, rebase `feature2` on `main` and then push to update the PR?
2. Suppose a user merges `feature2` PR for first (so `feature1` and `feature3` are still open). What happens to `feature1` PR? Is it merged automatically?Is it to merge? But in this case, what are its changes?

I didn't find an online guide about this

Answer (score 1):

> In that case, is the order in which the PRs will be merged is important?

Yes, the order is important.

> Suppose a user merges PR feature1, then if I visit the page of PR feature2, what I see?

You would see all the changes that `main` has compared to `feature2` branch. This will include the changes `feature1` brought.

> Only the differences of commit e-g or I need to pull main, rebase feature2 on main and then push to update the PR?

The best practice here is to rebase `feature2` on `feature1`.

> Suppose a user merges feature2 PR for first (so feature1 and feature3 are still open). What happens to feature1 PR? Is it merged automatically?

No, why would it be?

> Is it to merge?

Likely not.

> But in this case, what are its changes?

Once `feature2` is merged, then the merge request for `feature1` will show `main` being ahead of `feature1`.

Answer (score 0):

> In that case, is the order in which the PRs will be merged is important?

Only if one feature depends on what is developed by another feature.

If not, then the best practice is to rebase feature branches on top of their intended target:

- that helps resolving any potential conflict locally before the review and trivial merge
- that helps showing in the PR only one feature set of changes (instead of multiple feature changes)

In your case:

```bash
git switch main
git pull
git switch feature2
git rebase --onto main (git merge-base feature1 feature2) feature2
```